# UITableViewCell animation - displacement during animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am implementing an animation on my UITableView. Whenever I tap on my section I want all the rows under that section to collapse with an animation. A tap again will bring them back animated.

This is what I am doing:

1. Putting a tap gesture recognizer on my table sections & on the
   handler I am setting the table data sources accordingly.
2. After setting up correct data sources I am calling following code,
   here aTag is the section index tapped.

   [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:aTag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

Here, the problem I am facing is that when rows are animating I see them animating in wrong frame. My section header also animates from above & the whole animation looks displaced by height of section header. Once animation is done, everything is at correct place. It is just during the animation I see a little weirdness of animation displacement. So, ideally, only cell should animate & not the section & cell should animate from its position without any displacement.

Any idea what needs to be taken care of here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a UITableView bug. I spent a technical support ticket, and they told me to report it as a bug. Bug ID# 12498611.

The solution I've come up for this is:

- scroll the cells first out of the view
- update the backing data
- reload the table, as not to animate the cell removal
- scroll the table (without animation) to compensate for the missing cells

There are some edge cases for which you have to ensure that the content offset doesn't become negative or overshoots the content size. For this rectForSection is your best friend.

Hope this helped.